# XCode 6.4: Objective-C classes are not visible to code completion inside Swift 1.2 file

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode6

I am working with a project that has some classes written in Swift and some classes that are written in Objective-C and when working in a swift file non of the classes written in Objective-C are visible to code completion but all of the classes written in Swift are.

When I compile the project it builds and runs just fine and all the "errors" go away during compile time.

When I try to Command-Click a class name that has it's implementation written in Objective-C I get the error: "Symbol not found".

Any Ideas as to what went wrong? I did not have these issues in XCode 6.3.

Comment: It's been happening to me too the last weeks. It seems like a bug with Xcode 6.4. Anyway, this is not a programming issue but rather a software (IDE) one. I'm pretty sure this should not be here. EDIT: Oh, and for fixing it... I simply clean (cmd+shift+K) and then analyze (cmd+shift+B) when this happens.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but that did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experience similar problems (although bridging header was right and code compiles, the code completion in Swift doesn't) when I add Swift code to an existing Objective-C project. But code completion in the Swift code seems to work when I added Objective-C code to my Swift project.

Anyway, this was remedied by

1. Locating derived data folder:

   [image]
2. Exiting Xcode.
3. Emptying "derived data" folder.
4. Restarting Xcode and opening project again.